# How to read, encrypt, and overwrite a text file

Tags: c

I just want to take the content of the file and encrypt it on the same file.

I understand that it's not the most effective form of encryption, but I'm just playing around with it to see how the code reads files.

Hello.txt has "abcdefg".

But when I run the code through it, nothing changes.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    FILE *fp1=NULL;

    char ch;

    fp1=fopen("C:\\Hello.txt","r+");

    if(fp1==NULL)
    {
        printf("fp1 NULL!\n");
    }

    while(1){

        ch=fgetc(fp1);

        if(ch==EOF){
            printf("End of File\n");
            break;
        }
        else{
            ch=ch*10;
            fputc(ch,fp1);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First things first: [The `fgetc` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an `int`. This is really important for your `EOF` check.

Comment: Furthermore, what do you think will happen when you are multiplying an [ASCII character](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) by `10`? What is e.g. 97 (the ASCII value of `'a'`) multiplied by ten? How will that result fit in a byte?

Comment: Lastly, when you write to the file, where do you think that will be written? Think of a file much like an array in memory, and the file position like an index into the array. When you read a character from the file, it's increments the file position by one, so it now "points" to the next character to read. What will happen if you now *write* to that position?

Comment: Very bad to overwrite the input file. Every time you run the test, you'll have to recreate it for the next test.

Answer (score 0):

Joachim Pileborg already used the comments to hint at the errors you made, let me be less subtle:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// Cesar cipher
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  FILE *fp1 = NULL;
  // we need an int to check for EOF
  int ch;

  fp1 = fopen("Hello.txt", "r+");
  if (fp1 == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "fp1 NULL!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while (1) {
    // get character (fgetc returns an int)
    ch = fgetc(fp1);
    if (ch == EOF) {
      printf("End of File\n");
      break;
    } else {
      // Set file-pointer back to the position of 
      // the character just read (it is a bit more
      // complicated internally and works only for one)
      ungetc(ch, fp1);
      // do decryption
      if (argc == 2 && *argv[1] == 'd') {
        ch = ch - 3;
      }
      // do encrytion (default)
      else if (argc == 1 || (argc == 2 && *argv[1] == 'e')) {
        ch = ch + 3;
      }
      // print character (fputc takes an int)
      fputc(ch, fp1);
    }
  }
  fclose(fp1);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```